# Unable to find a match: centos-release-openstack-stein

Tags: centos, openstack

I am trying to install Openstack (stein) release on CentOS-8 following the steps provided in this guide - 
[OpenStack CentOS-7 install guide](https://www.tecmint.com/openstack-installation-guide-rhel-centos/).

My assumption is these CentOS-7 steps are same for CentOS-8. I am using 'dnf' instead of 'yum'.

```
systemctl stop postfix firewalld NetworkManager
systemctl disable postfix firewalld NetworkManager
systemctl mask NetworkManager
dnf remove postfix NetworkManager NetworkManager-libnm

setenforce 0
getenforce
vi /etc/selinux/config (changed the SELINUX line to 'disabled')
hostnamectl set-hostname cloud.centos.lan
dnf install network-scripts
systemctl enable network
systemctl start network
reboot
```

However, I am consistently running into the below error. No clue whatsoever why this is failing.

```
[root@cloud ~]# 
yum update -y
dnf install -y centos-release-openstack-stein

Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:04 ago on Fri 10 Apr 2020 12:52:13 PM PDT.
No match for argument: centos-release-openstack-stein
Error: Unable to find a match: centos-release-openstack-stein
[root@cloud ~]#
```

What is the solution for this error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not seen and I am able to follow the steps on CentOS-7. I am using the following CentOS-7.

The installation steps for CentOS-8 are still to be figured out.

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```